# “Cannot read properties of null” when I tried to get a DOM element after created it with useState()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io

I'm making an online shooting game with HTML, React, and socket.io and when a user makes a shot I get the necessary data to replicate the shot in the screen of the other user, but after create the bullet (which it is a div) I can't access to the element. I usually solve this kind of problems using useRef(), but in this case I think isn't possible.

very summarized the algorithm works like this:

1. Declare and render a useState called Bullets DivEnemy where I'm going to store the divs that are the shooted bullets from the other user

```
  const [bulletsDivEnemy, setBulletsDivEnemy] = useState([]);
//.
//.
//.
//.
// render in the DOM:
 {bulletsDivEnemy}
```

1. Detect when the other user makes a shot and get its data and call the "shotsOfEnemy" function

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {

   socket.on("receive_shoot", (data) => {
     shooting2(data)
    }) 
    
  }, [socket])
```

3. Into the function I update the bullet DivEnemy with the new bullet but when I try to animate it after having selected it with queryselector it gives me the error

```
function shotsOfEnemy(data){

    setBulletsDivEnemy((prevDivs) => {
  
        return [
          ...prevDivs,
          <div key={prevDivs.length}
            className={` h-1 absolute   z-50  origin-right bullet-parent`}
            style={{
              transform: `rotate(${data.bulletPath)deg)`,
              top: `${data.gunTop + 4}px `,
              right: `${data.gunXDistance}px`,
            }}
          >
              {/* the below div is the bullet */}
              <div
                className="bullet"
                id={`bullet-ene${bulletsDivLength}`}
              ></div>
         
          </div>,
        ];
      });

      
      const bullet = document.querySelector(`#bullet-ene${bulletsDivLength}`);
    // The bullet const is NULL!!!!!!!!!!
      

}
```